# contar vocales de lista de palabras en excel

Tags: excel, formulas

Tengo un excel con dos hojas, en la primera quiero mostrar el conteo de vocales y en la segunda quiero tener una lista de palabras.

Para ello en la columna C de la Hoja 1 tengo la lista de vocales.
En la columna A de la hoja 2 tengo la lista de palabras.

ejemplo:

Hoja 1

```
|Palabras totales|  Letra|
|5|a|
|   |b|
|   |c|
|   |d|
|   |e|
|   |f|
|   |g|
|   |h|
|   |i|
|   |j|
|   |k|
|   |l|
|   |m|
|   |n|
|   |ñ|
|   |o|
|   |p|
|   |q|
|   |r|
|   |s|
|   |t|
|   |u|
|   |v|
|   |w|
|   |x|
|   |y|
|   |z|
```

Hoja 2

```
acalli
acamaya
acatl
achitzin
acicamati
```

Hasta el momento he intentado

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A1:A1030,LEN(Sheet2!A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet2!A1,C3,"")))
```

Para obtener la cuenta de la primer celda estoy seguro que puedo usar

```
=LEN(Sheet2!A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet2!A1,C3,"")
```

en esta formula le quito la letra que quiero buscar y las veces que aarece es las diferencia entre la longitud del contenido menos la longitud del contenido sin la letra.
Mi problema radica en que no se como hacer la misma operacion en un rango sin crear una columna con los resultados intermedios antes de sumarlos.

Resultados esperados:

```
|Palabras totales|  Letra|Apariciones
|5|a|11
|   |b|0
|   |c|6
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

Ya he hallado una formula que resuelve mi problema, aunque seguramente hay mejores formas.

Para las primeras tres letras de la hoja uno quedaria:

```
=SUM(LEN(Sheet2!A1:A482)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet2!A1:A482,Sheet1!C3,"")))
=SUM(LEN(Sheet2!A1:A482)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet2!A1:A482,Sheet1!C4,"")))
=SUM(LEN(Sheet2!A1:A482)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet2!A1:A482,Sheet1!C5,"")))
```

en donde A482 es la ultima celda de la Hoja 2 que tiene valor. (En mi caso real tengo mas de las 5 palabas que puse de ejemplo.)

El valor de C3, C4, y C5 va a ir aumentando apra coincidir con la celda que tiene la letra que queramos contar.

Puntos debiles en esta solucion:

- se debe poner en todas las celdas cada que se cambie la ultima celda con valor o la funcion dara error ( no es tan mantenile como quisiera )

---

Solucion mejorada

```
=SUM(LEN(OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A),1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A),1),Sheet1!C3,"")))
=SUM(LEN(OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A),1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A),1),Sheet1!C4,"")))
=SUM(LEN(OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A),1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A),1),Sheet1!C5,"")))
```

El uso de `COUNTA` me regresa el numero de celdas que tienen valor en la columna A de la segunda hoja, mientras que el uso de `OFFSET` me permite definir el rango de manera dinamica, de manera que no necesito hacer la cuenta de palabras totales a mano en C3 para que la formula funcione.
De hecho se puede notar que en las otras celdas solo se incrementa el valor de la columna C que es donde esta la letra, lo cual de alguna manera reduce la complejidad al momento de entender las funciones

Comment: No entiendo los puntos débiles de tu solución. Te da justamente lo que quieres ¿no? Te da el número total de apariciones de cada letra. ¿Qué es lo que buscas?

Comment: @Esei checa mi solucion mejorada, a veces lo que quieres no es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Querías que se seleccionase automáticamente el rango sin tener que actualizarlo si se añadían datos nuevos. OFFSET es una función volátil y sobrecarga los archivos si tienes muchos datos. No se recomienda su uso. Considera usar un objeto tabla, que simplifica la formulación y hace justo lo que quieres (rango dinamico)

Comment: @Esei no era eso lo que queria, pero resulto ser lo que necesitaba